# Invite Leader Board sends multiple messages

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am building a code ,in Discord.js library with Node.js, of an Invite LeaderBoard command !

The code i am using is :

```
  module.exports = {
  name: 'leaderboard',
  description: 'Invites Leader Board',
  async execute(message, args, Discord, client){
     const { guild } = message

    guild.fetchInvites().then((invites) => {
      const inviteCounter = {}

      invites.forEach((invite) => {
        const { uses, inviter } = invite
        const { username, discriminator } = inviter

        const name = `${username}#${discriminator}`

        inviteCounter[name] = (inviteCounter[name] || 0) + uses
      })

      let replyText = 'Invites:'

      const sortedInvites = Object.keys(inviteCounter).sort(
        (a, b) => inviteCounter[b] - inviteCounter[a]
      )

      console.log(sortedInvites)

      sortedInvites.length = 10

      for (const invite of sortedInvites) {
        
        const count = inviteCounter[invite]
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('BLUE')
        .setTitle('`INVITES LEADERBOARD`')
        .setDescription(sortedInvites)
        message.channel.send(embed)
      }

      
    })
  }
}
```

The code comes with no errors but when I execute `!leaderboard` , bot sends 10 different messages with the same content. In additional I want to add more info to each user , like how many invites does the user got and how many are left from these invites ! My bot sends this[image] 10 times in row, what I want is : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop through the `sortedInvites` array 10 times and send a message every time, so this behavior should not surprise you. If you only want to send one message, remove the `send` from the loop.

Also, you only `sort` the keys of the `inviteCounter` object, so you loose the other data. In order to preserve the data, change it to this:

```
const sortedInvites = Object.keys(inviteCounter).sort().reduce(
  (obj, key) => { 
    obj[key] = inviteCounter[key]; 
    return obj;
  }, 
  {}
);
```

Then, if you want to display username next to data, you can create an array with the data like this and join it together with a new line to separate it from each other in the message:

```
const invitesData = Object.keys(sortedInvites).map(invite => {
  return `${invite}: ${sortedInvites[invite]}`;
});

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor("BLUE")
  .setTitle("`INVITES LEADERBOARD`")
  .setDescription(invitesData.join("\n"));
message.channel.send(embed);
```

Comment: That solved my problem . Now I am not facing errors but bot sends from bottom to begin. What I mean is , that if you have 1 invite and I have 2 invites , you will be in top and I will be in bottom!

Comment: Well, I think that is another question. It basically comes down to how best sort your invites. Currently you do it by name, so you should change it to the number of invites.